# Swift: How to pass Data into my shopping Cart(Array)?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, delegates

Im new here and trying to write my first little App in Swift. 
I have to program a little Book-Shopping-App but now I have a problem. 
If I press the "add to card"-Button in my DetailView I want to pass my Book-Data to my Shopping-Card-Class. The Shopping-Card-Class is a TableView with an Array.
So this my DetailView: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160120/tpsdezys.png

If I press this I want to pass it to my Shopping-Card-Class/Screen, here:
http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160120/qhsbi6aq.png

In my DetailView is all the book stuff like :
var autorName: String?
var title: String?
var price: String?
var image: String?

And in the Shopping-Card-Class is a Array, thats it, but I dont know how to pass the data :/

If I press the button I just add the book, I dont switch the screens.

I've used Delegates before but never in combination with arrays, 
pls help :/
I used it here, look: fs5.directupload.net/images/160121/8zmfqef4.png
and passed the data to this screen:
fs5.directupload.net/images/160121/2263tiwl.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest starting [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/)!
Once you go through these solutions, you will have a much better understanding on how to pass information between ViewControllers. As a hunt you will need to mess around with the prepareForSegue method and use a segue identifier in order to see which view controller you are jumping to, then setting an instance variable of that class equal to the data you have available in this class. This essentially passes the data from one class to the other.

Comment: Hey, I've used delegates before, but never in combination with a array :/
I used it here, look: [collectionView](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160121/8zmfqef4.png)
and passed the data to this screen:
[DetailView](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160121/2263tiwl.png)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "If I press the button I just add the book I don't switch screens." Are you saying when a book is clicked on, it doesn't open the detailVC or that it opens but the book that it opens is just a generic book and not the specific book you clicked on? Or is it just a matter of sending data back from the detailVC to the TableView?

Comment: So I want to buy that book, which I see in the DetailView, so I click/press the Button "add to card". You can see this DetailView here:
[link](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160120/tpsdezys.png)

After I press the "add to card"-Button I want that all the information of this book, goes to an array which is in the Add-To-Card-Class. In this class I have a Array, which is connected to a tableView.
You can see it here: 
[link](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160120/qhsbi6aq.png)

Comment: So I'm just shopping in the app, I see one book that I like, so I click to "add to card", then I go on and see another book that I like, and again add this book to my card too.And at the end of shopping I go to the Add-To-Card-Class ,which is a tableview and there I can see all the book that I will want to buy.

Comment: I think its something like you said "Or is it just a matter of sending data back from the detailVC to the TableView?", but not sendig back, just sendig to another tableview...

Comment: Ok, I've got it. I used a singleton :) ty

Comment: @Perazim 3 years after yours I am in same situation did not find any solution about one week. So, your codes alive about this problem ? :)

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci hey, I guess I cant help you anymore. This was 3 years ago and I cant remember how I fixed it. But you see that I wrote "I used a singleton", so I guess that I took my Add-To-Card-Class and turned it into a singleton, so I could pass all the books to the right instance/object

And I guess that I went through this tutorial to understand how it works: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/